# FATAL EXCEPTION: main ... Cargar consulta SQLite a arrayList y pasarlo a Recyclerview

Tags: java, android, sqlite, cursor, arrayadapter

Hola tengo un proyecto en Android y lo que necesito es pasar los datos de un cursor, es decir un query a un arraylist, y luego pasar ese array a otro para "mapear" cada columna del cursor en una clase para mostrar los datos en un recyclerview. Espero de verdad haberme dado a entender. Gracias.
Error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.home.sb, PID: 21843
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Estatus"
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:521)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:556)
at com.example.home.sb.items.InicioItem.imgBackground(InicioItem.java:31)
at com.example.home.sb.recyclerAdapters.InicioRecyclerAdapter.onBindViewHolder(InicioRecyclerAdapter.java:84)
at com.example.home.sb.recyclerAdapters.InicioRecyclerAdapter.onBindViewHolder(InicioRecyclerAdapter.java:25)
```

Metodo para buscar datos dentro de mi clase conexcion extends SQLiteOpenHelper:

```
public Cursor buscardatos_Inicio(String IdG){
String inicio[]= new String[]{Inicio.id, Inicio.Monto, Inicio.MontoActual, Inicio.Monto_Garantizado, Inicio.Tipo_Garantia, Inicio.Tipo_Juicio, Inicio.Estatus...};
cursor= this.getReadableDatabase().query(Inicio.TInicio, inicio, Inicio.IdG+ "=?", new String[]{"%"+IdG+"%"},null,null,null);
return cursor;
}
```

Cargar array en un Fragment

```
public class InicioFragment extends Fragment {
    public RecyclerView recyclerView;
    public RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
    public RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    public SearchView searchView;
    public Context context;
    public ArrayList<InicioItem> arrayList;
    Inicio inicio;
    SQLiteDatabase bd;
    public ArrayList<String> listCreditos;
    private conexion con;
    String idG;
    Cursor cursor;

     @Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)              View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_inicio, container, false);
   idG=getArguments().getString("idG");
   inicio= new Inicio();
   recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.rclvInicio);
   recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
   searchView = (SearchView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.searchInicio);
   this.context = this.getContext();
   arrayList = new ArrayList<InicioItem>();
   listCreditos=new  ArrayList<String>();

   getContacts();
   arrayList=GetArrayListInicioItem();
   adapter = new InicioRecyclerAdapter(context, (ArrayList) arrayList);
   recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
   layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
   recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
   return rootView;
   }

  public String[] getContacts(){
  try {
  con=new conexion(context);
  con.open();
  cursor=con.buscardatos_Inicio(idG.toString());
  if (cursor != null) {
  cursor.moveToFirst();
  do {               listCreditos.add(String.valueOf(cursor.getCount()));
  }while(cursor.moveToNext());
  }
  cursor.close();
  }catch (Exception e){
  e.printStackTrace();
  }
  return listCreditos.toArray(new String[listCreditos.size()]);
  }

  public ArrayList<InicioItem> GetArrayListInicioItem(){
  try{if(listCreditos != null) {
  for (int i = 0; i < listCreditos.size(); i++) {
  arrayList.add(new InicioItem(inicio));
  }  }  }  catch (Exception e){
  e.printStackTrace();
  } return arrayList;
  }

 }
```

Adapter

```
public class InicioRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<InicioRecyclerAdapter.InicioRecyclerViewHolder> implements Filterable {//columna 25
    private ArrayList<InicioItem> arrayList = new ArrayList<InicioItem>();
    private static ArrayList<InicioItem> arrayListInicio = new ArrayList<InicioItem>();

    public InicioRecyclerAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<InicioItem> arrayList) {
        this.context = context;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.arrayList = arrayList;
        this.arrayListInicio = arrayList;
    }

    @Override
    public InicioRecyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_inicio_layout, parent, false);
    InicioRecyclerViewHolder inicioRecyclerViewHolder = new InicioRecyclerViewHolder(view);
    return inicioRecyclerViewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(InicioRecyclerViewHolder holder, int position) {

    InicioItem inicioItem = arrayList.get(position);
```

holder.imgvInicioImgBackground.setImageResource(inicioItem.imgBackground());//columna 84
holder.imgvInicioImg.setImageResource(inicioItem.img());
holder.txtvInicioNombre.setText(inicioItem.nombre());
    }

InicioItem Class

```
  public class InicioItem { 
  private Inicio _inicio;
  public InicioItem(Inicio inicio) {
  this._inicio=inicio;
  }
  public Inicio inicio(){
  return _inicio;
  }
  public int imgBackground(){
  int imgbackground = R.drawable.background_item_red;
  if(_inicio != null){
  switch (Integer.parseInt(_inicio.Estatus.toString())){//columna 31
  case 0: //NO ASIGNADO
  imgbackground =  R.drawable.background_item_red;
  break;
  case 1: //ACTIVO
  imgbackground =  R.drawable.background_item_teal;
  break;
  }
  }return imgbackground;
  }

  public int img(){
  int img = R.drawable.ic_item_n;
  if(_inicio != null){
  switch (Integer.parseInt(_inicio.Estatus)){
  case 0: //NO ASIGNADO
  img =  R.drawable.ic_item_a;
  break;
  case 1: //ACTIVO
  img =  R.drawable.ic_item_b;
  break;
  }}
  return img;
  }

  ...etc
```

Class Inicio

```
public class Inicio {
    public static final String TInicio="Inicio";
    public static final String id="id";
    public static final String Nombre="Nombre";
    public static final String IdGr="IdG";
    public static final String Estatus="Estatus";
    ...etc

     public static final String crearInicio="create table "+TInicio+"("+id+" integer primary key autoincrement, "+Nombre+" text, "+...+" etc)";
     }
```

Comment: Pon la traza de error y el código del layout que da el error

Comment: @javierMollá gracias por responder, la app se detiene, en return rootView en el public View onCreateView del Fragment., realmente no muestre como tal un error, he puesto try catch pero ni asi lo muestra

Comment: Mira en la ventana de Logcat y debería haber algo referente al error

Comment: @JaviMollá ya lo he agregado

Comment: @Geek revisa el internet en tu dispositivo, esta teniendo problemas esa es la razón por la cual se despliega ese mensaje en el LogCat.

Comment: Hola, mi dispositivo si tiene acceso a internet correctamente

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error esta en

```
  private Inicio _inicio; ....  
  int imgbackground =     R.drawable.background_item_red;  
 if(_inicio != null)
 {  
 switch (Integer.parseInt(_inicio.Estatus.toString())){//columna
```

La variable **Estatus** de tu clase **_inicio** es un String con la cadena *"Estatus* al intentar convertirla a un entero, lo cual es imposible, te da el error que ves:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException:
```

Tendras que cambiar la variable Estatus a int  y ponle un cero  o un uno, como luego compruebas en el switch.

Saludos